# C++ - TC++PL RTTI dynamic_cast downcasting and virtual table confusion (as well as in its implementation)

Tags: c++, internal

I am reading RTTI from "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)" by B. Stroustrup. English is not my first language and I am not sure whether I have come to correct conclusion from its explanation of downcasting mechanism using `dynamic_cast<T*>(p)`. I am quoting the text from the book

> Requiring the pointer’s type to be polymorphic simplifies the
>   implementation of dynamic_cast because it makes it easy to find a
>   place to hold the necessary information about the object’s type. A
>   typical implementation will attach a ‘‘type information object’’
>   (§22.5) to an object by placing a pointer to the type information in
>   the virtual function table for the object’s class (§3.2.3). For
>   example:
>   [image: The image explaining the downcast]
>   The dashed arrow represents an offset that allows the start of the
>   complete object to be found given only a pointer to a polymorphic
>   subobject. It is clear that dynamic_cast can be efficiently
>   implemented. All that is involved are a few comparisons of type_info
>   objects representing base classes; no expensive lookups or string
>   comparisons are needed.

My confusion comes from the line *"The dashed arrow represents an offset that allows the start of the complete object to be found given
only a pointer to a polymorphic subobject."*

My deductions from this line are:

- That there is a pointer to base (or subobject) stored in **vtbl** (virtual function table) and the dashed lines are representing pointer to subobject
- This contradicts with the second part of the line i.e. *given only a pointer to a polymorphic subobject*. But it creates more confusion, how can we pass a pointer to subobject. While downcasting we pass the derived class name **T** in **<>** brackets and the pointer to the base class object **p** in **()** brackets of `dynamic_cast<T*>(p)` syntax.

As a complete process if my first point is plausible or considered true.
Then can we say my following Hypothesis holds true?

**Hypothesis** :: While downcasting, the type information object (`type_info`) pointed by a pointer present in the virtual function table (vtbl) is compared successively against the base class's `type_id`. If `type_id` of **p**(or object pointed by p) is found in the former mentioned comparisons then, an object of derived class is created. Since the pointer to subobject is stored in the virtual table, we memcpy (or something similar to that) the base class object which we got from **p** (which is an input argument to `dynamic_cast<T*>(p)`) to the subobject of the drived class(which we found from the pointer present in the virtual function table).

I have googled for this but didn't found any possible explanation. If I am offtopic then kindly direct me to the correct StackExchange module.

P.S : On the side note, the topic 3.2.3 explain virtual table in the book. Which concludes with lines.

> This virtual call mechanism can be made almost as efficient as the
>   ‘‘normal function call’’ mechanism (within 25%).

What does within 25% mean here. Again I have my hypothesis for this, but it would be better if someone states their conclusions to me.

Lastly, any information on how cross-cast is identified or implemented by dynamic_cast will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no copying going on, as all the objects (subobjects) are present all along. There might be several bases classes, some of which might have a virtual inheritance.

The pointers (possibly stored as an offset, and not a fixed address) in the vtables is one way to help the runtime find where the different subobjects start inside the whole object. Or to find the start of the full object from a pointer to a subobject. Obviously, only the first base  class can be located at the start of the object, the others will have to be located as `start + offset`.

A virtual call can be almost as efficient as a direct function call. At the machine code level, a function call is just coded as `call address_of_function`, where the address is stored inside the instruction.

A virtual call can be implemented as `call *(vtable + offset)`. If the vtable address is stored in a register, many CPUs have support for doing this indirection in a single instruction. The cost is one extra memory access for fetching the real function address. If the function does anything significant, this extra memory access will not make much of a difference.